# Can I copy the narrative structure of a movie?

Tags: memento, short-films, copyright

Will there be any copyright issues if I make a short movie with EXACTLY the same narrative structure as the Hollywood movie "Memento", but with totally different story? Also, do I need to credit them (the makers of Memento) for the narrative structure of my short movie?

Comment: It seems that your question is about legal stuff, I am not sure this is on topic on this site...

Comment: @mattiav27 no. I just wanted to know if one can copy only the narrative structure of a movie without copying the story of that movie.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has to do with legal issues.

Comment: @bcdotweb since when does that make it off topic? Should we close any and all questions about the FCC or censorship as well?

Comment: @cde it's asking for specific legal advice... it's not asking for general rules.

Comment: So the difference being, what, that they used "I" instead of "someone" and named a specific movie instead of "a movie"? That's pedantic.

Comment: BTW, the backwards story concept was used before *Memento* in a *Seinfeld* episode, so if anyone holds rights on it (and I don't think that kind of thing can be protected IP), it wouldn't be the writers of *Memento* anyway. Apparently the *Seinfeld* episode took it from a Pinter play called *The Betrayal*.

Comment: @Catija I am very much aware that this is a stack exchange for movies and tv, and not for legal issues.I was just curious whether the peculiar narrative structure like that of Memento can be used in other movies or not. As "@cde" said it may have been confusing due to the fact that I used "I" instead of "someone" and named a specific movie instead of "a movie".

Comment: @cde Thanks.You totally understood my question. It seems the word "copyright" made it sound more of legal issue question, but truely got my intention of asking the question.

Comment: @NisH Your question is about you writing a movie, and thus doesn't belong here, but for instance on http://writers.stackexchange.com/ . Your suggestion about that group shows that you don't know how SE works.

Comment: @cde This question isn't about an existing movie or TV-series, but about one that NisH might or might not write. Thus making it off-topic according to http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: @bcdotweb I see On topic `Questions about a Movie or TV show's production.`

`Our on topic content also includes Made-For-TV movies, Web-series, Direct-to-DVD, and Mini-Series.` We also have many questions about movies still in production. What in that link do you think makes this question off topic?

Comment: @bcdotweb and from what I see, this would not be on topic over at writers. Don't suggest a place if it's not on topic there.

Comment: @cde This isn't "in production". This is barely an idea in someone's head. It isn't any of those things you quoted. And why wouldn't it be on topic @ http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenwriting ?

Comment: @BCdotWEB First you said my question is off topic because "it has to do with legal issue". Now you are saying its off topic because  "its about I writing a movie". First, please clarify yourself  why its off topic then suggest me "some perfect words" so that I can edit my question which will ultimately be on topic for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. But I am not a lawyer, and very powerful lawyers may think otherwise, and while you may win a lawsuit over it, it will be expensive.

From an educational lawyer copyright blog https://library.osu.edu/blogs/copyright/

> While the requisite level of creativity is low, **copyright will not protect ideas (including narrative structure or general plotlines), concepts, or common themes.**
>
> In addition, there may be situations in which there are only a limited number of ways to express an idea. If this situation exists, the idea merges with the expression, and the expression becomes uncopyrightable (this is referred to as the merger doctrine in copyright law). **Similarly, copyright will not protect standard expressions or stock characters or events that are ordinary to a particular subject matter (this is referred to as the scènes à faire doctrine in copyright law). The structure of a knock-knock joke, for example, cannot be copyrighted.**

The general concept is that Expressions of an Idea are copyrightable, but not the general idea itself. Which is why you could have multiple movies about blowing up an Asteroid, or any number of nearly identical love stories, or comedies, or anything.